# I have a basic Update Where statement that is sytaxticly correct but does not update the table

Tags: java, mysql

This is the code:

```
@Override public void update(){
    Statement stmt = null;
    String company = "";
    try {
        Connect conn = new Connect();
        stmt = conn.makeStatement();
        // This creates the SQL statement to update an existing student.
        System.out.println("Update employee"
                         + " Set employeeID = employeeID,"
                         + " firstName = firstName,"
                         + " lastName = lastName,"
                         + " paRating = paRating,"
                         + " status = status,"
                         + " manager = managerr,"
                         + " level = level,"
                         + " company = company"
                         + " WHERE employeeID = " + get EmployeeID() 
                         + "Limit 1");

        stmt.execute("Update employee"
                         + " Set employeeID = employeeID,"
                         + " firstName = firstName,"
                         + " lastName = lastName,"
                         + " paRating = paRating,"
                         + " status = status,"
                         + " manager = managerr,"
                         + " level = level,"
                         + " company = company"
                         + " WHERE employeeID = " + get EmployeeID() 
                         + "Limit 1");

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Unable to update employee in the database.");
    } finally {
    }
    System.out.println("Employee successfully updated to the database.");
 }
```

I am assuming I have missed something simple & obvious that i just can't see.

Comment: What should this code do?

Comment: Are you getting an error message from the catch block?

Comment: maybe get rid of all that punctuation

Comment: Your query doesn't look like it's valid. What values are you trying to set all the fields to?

Comment: You seem to be asking to set everything to itself (except manager(r))

Answer (score 2):

This query doesn't update anything - it just sets a whole lot of columns to their existing values.  If you want to update them to something else, you'd better pass those "something else" values in somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I note, you probably want a space between `getEmployeeID()` and `Limit 1`; Also, assuming you're not running with [autoCommit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) enabled, you need to call [Connection.commit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit%28%29). Finally, you should close your connection and statement objects in the `finally` block.